# Can Redis Cache store the time to live (ttl) for each items in a list?

Tags: list, caching, redis, set, ttl

As I understand redis cache is like a dictionary key-value, so if I have a key and a list, can I set ttl individually for each items in the list?

```
item1 - ttl 5000
item2 - ttl 7000
item3 - ttl 8500
```

Comment: The TTL in Redis is for the key, so no, you cannot have different TTLs for the elements of a single list.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set ttl individually for each items in the list. But if you really necessary want to implement this, I recommend solution like this:

- Use SORTED SET (ZSET) with score = timestamp

insert element

```
ZADD yourlist 5000 item1    
ZADD yourlist 7000 item2
ZADD yourlist 8500 item3
```

get sorted value from infinity to infinity

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE mykey -inf inf
```

remove value (from -infinity to 6000) => item1 will be deleted

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE mykey -inf 6000
```

You can get sorted value from infinity to infinity again to see result.